# Why does data breakpoint not work on unaligned address

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, breakpoints

In Visual Studio while debugging a C++ project,
some data breakpoints never hit.

So I wrote some code for testing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

void test(uint32_t* p)
{
    *p = 0;

    // set a data breakpoint on p

    *((char*)p + 2) = 0x1;

    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
}

uint32_t* alloc(size_t offset)
{
    char* p = new char[sizeof(uint32_t) + offset];
    p = p + offset;
    return (uint32_t*)p;
}

int main()
{
    test(alloc(0));    // test #1
    test(alloc(2));    // test #2
}
```

As you see, in function test, the value of *p will be zeroed first,
then it will be changed implicitly, I got a litte-endian CPU so it
must be 65536.

If you set a data breakpoint on p (4 bytes) to detect the changing,
you'll get two different results: hit or not. It depends on the
address of that p pointed at.

In my testing code above, test #1 will hit and test #2 will not,
the difference between #1 and #2 are the addresses returned by
alloc(0) and alloc(2).

This article [How to: Set a Data Breakpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/350dyxd0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN does not talk about this.

Does data breakpoint not work on an unaligned address ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data breakpoints are set with the assistance of the CPU, using the debug registers on x86; about them, the Intel manual says (§17.2.5):

> Breakpoint address registers (debug registers `DR0` through `DR3`) and the `LENn` fields for each breakpoint define a
>   range of sequential byte addresses for a data or I/O breakpoint. The `LENn` fields permit specification of a 1-, 2-, 4-
>   , or 8-byte range, beginning at the linear address specified in the corresponding debug register (DRn). **Two-byte
>   ranges must be aligned on word boundaries; 4-byte ranges must be aligned on doubleword boundaries.** I/O
>   addresses are zero-extended (from 16 to 32 bits, for comparison with the breakpoint address in the selected debug
>   register). These requirements are enforced by the processor; it uses LENn field bits to mask the lower address bits
>   in the debug registers. **Unaligned data or I/O breakpoint addresses do not yield valid results.**

(emphasis added)

So, the limitation is in hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Detailed explanation of why this happens:

Data breakpoints use the CPU's debug registers. On x86 these debug registers get aligned to their data size by masking the address' lower bits:

- 16bits (2 bytes) breakpoints get its lowest address bit cleared `(addr & -2)`.
- 32bits (4 bytes) breakpoints get its 2 lowest address bits cleared `(addr & -4)`.
- 64bits (8 bytes) breakpoints get its 3 lowest address bits cleared `(addr & -8)`.

When the x86 CPU access memory it compares the address by masking it in the same way to the debug register address and **if the two are equal** it triggers a breakpoint.

---

This is a trick to simplify the electronic circuit in the debug breakpoint comparator: Only the two aligned addresses need to be compared.

Electronically it translates to the pseudo-code:

```
if(!((address ^ debug_address) & debug_mask))
    breakpoint();
```

Instead of:

```
if((address >= debug_address) & (address < debug_address_plus_length))
    breakpoint();
```

Which would be much more complex to implement in silicon and slow down the CPU. Even in software the first one would run faster.

The address-masking trick works perfectly as long as all memory accesses are aligned.

---

So let's say *p* points to address **0xF02** and the breakpoint is 32bits (4 bytes), then the breakpoint address gets aligned to `((0xF02 & -4) == 0xF00)`.

*note: -4 is 0xFFFFFFFC (32bits) or 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC (64bits)*

You then access the address (0xF02+2 == 0xF04)

The CPU then masks 0xF04 `((0xF04 & -4) == 0xF04)` before comparing it to the debug breakpoint address (0xF00).

They don't match so the CPU does not trigger the breakpoint.